# Can I find a bitcoin wallet from an address directly from blockchain data? (not website)

Tags: wallet, address

For example

https://www.walletexplorer.com/wallet/03457b955f9c055c/addresses shows all the addresses linked to wallet 03457b955f

How do they do that?

Thank you !!

Comment: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Privacy#Blockchain_attacks_on_privacy many techniques, mostly "common input"

Comment: Just to make sure you're aware: there is no such thing as a unique wallet identifier in Bitcoin. The association between addresses and wallets is a *guess* by that website, and the 03457b955f is an identifier chosen by walletexplorer.com for the observed cluster of (presumed related) addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **How do they do that?**

See https://www.walletexplorer.com/info

> **What is on this site?**
>
> WalletExplorer.com is Bitcoin blockchain explorer, with two additional features:
>
> 1. it merges addresses together, if WalletExplorer thinks that they are part of the same wallet
> 2. wallet can have name
>
> **How wallets are computed? When are addresses merged together?**
>
> Just a basic algorithm is used to determine wallet addresses. Addresses are merged together, if they are co-spent in one transaction. So if addresses A and B are co-spent in transaction T1, and addresses B and C are co-spent in transaction T2, all addresses A, B and C will be part of one wallet.
>
> Sometimes, an address belongs to some service but it was never co-spent with others. Then that address stays unnamed. It is typically more often at addresses with higher amount (as there is no need to co-spending).
>
> **How are names discovered?**
>
> In most of the cases, I registered to service, made transaction(s) and saw which wallet bitcoins were merged with, or from which wallet it was withdrawn.
>
> There is probably no easier way how to discover names other than this.
>
> Please note that the name database is not updated, so it does not contain newer exchanges (or newer wallets of existing exchanges)